# Compose plus apostrophe doesn't work with Cyrillic

Tags: input, compose-key

I used to have a custom .XCompose, I removed it to possibly eliminate the cause. Unfortunately, the problem persists - I can't create an accented Cyrillic character, such as the ones here [1]. Simply nothing happens when I press compose, apostrophe, а. I know it did work some (long) time ago, but I can't recall anything that could be the reason.

[1] https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C

Answer (score 0):

This problems has two roots.

1. The input method was set to `auto` in my case. I had to set it to `xim`.
2. Not all letters are covered by the default Compomse, you need to create an `.XCompose` and add the following lines to it:

   ```
   <dead_acute> <Cyrillic_ya>          : "я́"      # CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER Я WITH COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
   <Multi_key> <acute> <Cyrillic_ya>       : "я́"      # CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER Я WITH COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
   <Multi_key> <apostrophe> <Cyrillic_ya>      : "я́"      # CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER Я WITH COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT

   <dead_acute> <Cyrillic_yu>          : "ю́"      # CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER Ю WITH COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
   <Multi_key> <acute> <Cyrillic_yu>       : "ю́"      # CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER Ю WITH COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
   <Multi_key> <apostrophe> <Cyrillic_yu>      : "ю́"      # CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER Ю WITH COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT

   <dead_acute> <Cyrillic_u>           : "у́"      # CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER У WITH COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
   <Multi_key> <acute> <Cyrillic_u>        : "у́"      # CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER У WITH COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
   <Multi_key> <apostrophe> <Cyrillic_u>       : "у́"      # CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER У WITH COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT

   <dead_acute> <Cyrillic_y>           : "ы́"      # CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER У WITH COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
   <Multi_key> <acute> <Cyrillic_y>        : "ы́"      # CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER У WITH COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
   <Multi_key> <apostrophe> <Cyrillic_y>       : "ы́"      # CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER У WITH COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
   ```